# No result from ravenDB with node.js

Tags: node.js, ravendb

After 6 years in other languages I try to come back to node.js with an NoSQL DB.
I've implemented a first short application, where I want to get an Object from a ravenDB Database by a given value.
The database includes airports. I want to search them by using the IATA code.
My small application looks like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});

const { DocumentStore } = require('ravendb');
const store = new DocumentStore('http://localhost:5555', 'airportlist');
store.initialize();
const session = store.openSession();

app.get("/airportByIata/:iata", (req, res, next) => {
    var airport = session.query({ collection: "airports" }).whereEquals("iatacode", req.params.iata).first();
    res.json(JSON.parse(JSON.safeStringify(airport)));
});
```

This always returns me an empty object, but when I use the query direct in the ravenDB, I get the result.
My Query: **"from 'airports' where iatacode = 'CGN'"**

If I only ask for the collection without the where clause (**var airport = session.query({ collection: "airports" });**) then I get the following result:

```
{
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 1,
"_aliasToGroupByFieldName": {},
"_defaultOperator": "AND",
"_rootTypes": {},
"_queryParameters": {},
"_selectTokens": [],
"_whereTokens": [],
"_groupByTokens": [],
"_orderByTokens": [],
"_documentIncludes": {},
"_queryStats": {},
"_highlightingTokens": [],
"_queryHighlightings": {
"_highlightings": []
},
"_isGroupBy": false,
"_collectionName": "airports",
"_fromToken": {
"_collectionName": "airports",
"_dynamic": true,
"_alias": null
},
"_theSession": {
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 0,
"_clientSessionId": 1,
"_pendingLazyOperations": [],
"_hash": 1,
"_jsonSerializer": {
"_reviverRules": [
{}
],
"_replacerRules": [
{}
]
},
"deletedEntities": {},
"_knownMissingIds": {},
"documentsById": {
"_inner": {
"keysCaseSensitive": false
}
},
"includedDocumentsById": {
"keysCaseSensitive": false
},
"documentsByEntity": {},
"_numberOfRequests": 0,
"_deferredCommands": [],
"deferredCommandsMap": {},
"_generateDocumentKeysOnStore": true,
"_id": "4a84549a-0b84-4033-845a-79d8d4955e41",
"_databaseName": "airportlist",
"_documentStore": {
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 0,
"_urls": [
"http://localhost:5555"
],
"_lastRaftIndexPerDatabase": {
"keysCaseSensitive": false
},
"_eventHandlers": [],
"_subscriptions": {
"_subscriptions": {}
},
"_log": {},
"_databaseChanges": {},
"_requestExecutors": {},
"_database": "airportlist",
"_conventions": {
"_listOfQueryValueToObjectConverters": [],
"_registeredIdConventions": {},
"_registeredIdPropertyNames": {},
"_idPropertyCache": {},
"_readBalanceBehavior": "None",
"_identityPartsSeparator": "/",
"_identityProperty": "id",
"_maxNumberOfRequestsPerSession": 30,
"_maxHttpCacheSize": 134217728,
"_knownEntityTypes": {},
"_objectMapper": {
"_throwMappingErrors": false,
"_dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS0000"
},
"_useCompression": null,
"_dateUtilOpts": {},
"_dateUtil": {},
"_frozen": true
},
"_multiDbHiLo": {
"_generators": {},
"_dbName": "airportlist"
},
"_initialized": true
},
"_requestExecutor": {
"_updateDatabaseTopologySemaphore": {
"capacity": 1,
"current": 0,
"queue": [],
"firstHere": false
},
"_updateClientConfigurationSemaphore": {
"capacity": 1,
"current": 0,
"queue": [],
"firstHere": false
},
"_failedNodesTimers": {},
"_certificate": null,
"aggressiveCaching": null,
"numberOfServerRequests": 1,
"_clientConfigurationEtag": 0,
"_topologyEtag": 16,
"_log": {},
"_cache": {
"_items": {}
},
"_readBalanceBehavior": "None",
"_databaseName": "airportlist",
"_lastReturnedResponse": "2020-05-02T15:05:01.288Z",
"_conventions": {
"_readBalanceBehavior": "None",
"_identityPartsSeparator": "/",
"_identityProperty": "id",
"_maxNumberOfRequestsPerSession": 30,
"_maxHttpCacheSize": 134217728,
"_useCompression": null,
"_frozen": true
},
"_defaultRequestOptions": {
"gzip": true
},
"_firstTopologyUpdatePromiseInternal": {},
"_firstTopologyUpdateStatus": {
"_status": "RESOLVED"
},
"_nodeSelector": {
"_state": {
"speedTestMode": 1,
"topology": {
"etag": 16,
"nodes": [
{
"clusterTag": "A",
"url": "http://localhost:5555",
"serverRole": "Member",
"database": "airportlist"
}
]
},
"failures": [
0
],
"fastestRecords": [
0
]
}
},
"_updateTopologyTimer": {
"_periodInMs": 60000,
"_firstTimeDelayId": {
"_idleTimeout": 60000,
"_idlePrev": {
"expiry": 60877,
"id": -9007199254740990,
"msecs": 60000,
"priorityQueuePosition": 3
},
"_idleStart": 877,
"_repeat": null,
"_destroyed": false
}
},
"_topologyTakenFromNode": {
"database": "airportlist",
"url": "http://localhost:5555"
}
},
"maxNumberOfRequestsPerSession": 30,
"_generateEntityIdOnTheClient": {},
"_entityToJson": {
"_missingDictionary": {}
},
"_sessionInfo": {
"_sessionId": 1,
"_lastClusterTransactionIndex": null,
"_noCaching": false
},
"_valsCount": 0,
"_customCount": 0
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am suspecting the second part of you get request is not triggered due to the async nature of the call. What happens if you omit the parsing and just console log the res.json(airport) ?

Comment: The result of the console log is "Promise { <pending> }".

Comment: @CyberMessiah, thanks, your hint helped me to find the solution.
I need to make the complete method async to get a result:

app.get("/airportByIata/:iata", async (req, res, next) => {
    var airport = await session.query({ collection: "airports" }).whereEquals("iatacode", req.params.iata).first();
    console.log(airport);
    res.json(JSON.parse(JSON.safeStringify(airport)));
});

Comment: I will write it as an answer, if you don't mind somebody else might find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the asynchronous nature of the call, the second portion is triggered before the first is completed. The proper solution is to re-do the get request with async.